# Execute shell script in remote machine using Jenkins

Tags: git, shell, jenkins

My requirement is like this:
The jenkins is installed in one server(say server A).
I have 3 script in this server for deployment of war into different server say **B and C**.

There is a main script say **JenkinsMainScript.sh** . Inside this script I have copied the deployment script(say **serverB.sh/serverC.sh**)  from server A to the Corresponding server  serverB or serverC based on parameter passed when execute the shell like :

/root/Pictures/JenkinsTesting/JenkinsBuildMain.sh B

in the jenkins's "**Execute shell**" under "**Build**" section of **jenkins** of a job
where B is the server Name to deploy.
i.e if I again pass C as parameter in the above statement then the main script will copy serverC.sh from server A to server C and deploy the war into that server
Note:-All the deployment steps are written inside serverC.sh for server C  and serverB.sh for Server B.

Again My deployment is of two steps in jenkins, **Job1 and Job2.**

1.Create war file by taking source as git repository which is access using SSH(say server D)
2.After Successful execution of Job1 it will trigger Job2.

Inside Job2 I am executing the JenkinsBuildMain.sh file under **Build** section.

The Problem is If I add id_rsa and id_rsa.pub file inside .ssh directory of jenkins to access git server(server D) at the same time I can't access other server like server B for deployment via SSH connection.
Again if I add id_rsa and id_rsa.pub file inside .ssh for deployment server(server B) then Git server is unable to access at the same time.
That means only one server is accessible using SSH connection at a time.

Is there any way to access both server using same key or different key?

Or can we add multiple key for ssh connection so that it can access to both server, **server D** for git clone and server B for copying the script file from jenkins server to **server B**.

When I do this I got Bellow Message:
**"Host key verification failed.
lost connection"**

Current I am able connect one server at a time. If It connect to Git server the shell script file is not able to copy ,saying above error, and if I able set up for copying the file the git Server is unable to access saying

**Return status code 128.
Permission denied (PublicKey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-mic,password)....**

**Is There any way to add multiple keys for ssh connection for different server using Jenkins?**

Bellow is my script Code to copy the deploy script to remote server.

***JenkinsMainScript.sh:***

```
if [ $serverId = 'B' ]
    then        
        scp $scriptSourcePath/serverB.sh $serverBPathToCopyTheFile/
        ssh -l $serverBUserName $IpAddr $serverBPathToExecuteTheFile/serverB.sh

else
        echo " No Matching condition found..."
fi
```

Here is the screen shot of Configuration in the Jenkins for job2:

[Jenkins Config for job2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzf9I.png)

Can anyone help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing `scp $scriptSourcePath/serverB.sh $serverBPathToCopyTheFile/` directly, which using the default `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private key file, you can pass this `private key` as an argument.

Both `scp`, `ssh` accepts private key file as an argument. use argument `-i <file path>` for that purpose. You can do `man ssh` to know about all the command line options. Hope this makes sense for you.

```
ssh -i <private key file path> ...
scp -i <private key file path> ...
```

`man ssh` is showing following result for option `i`.

```
-i identity_file
         Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public key authenti-
         cation is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
         ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa.  Identity files may also be specified on
         a per-host basis in the configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple
         -i options (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).  If no
         certificates have been explicitly specified by the CertificateFile directive,
         ssh will also try to load certificate information from the filename obtained
         by appending -cert.pub to identity filenames.
```

`man scp` is showing following result for option `i`.

```
     -i identity_file
         Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public key authen-
         tication is read.  This option is directly passed to ssh(1).
```

Comment: Did it help you?